# The Ajax function returns data on 1 at the end

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am getting some html code with Ajax.
I retrieve the code. But at the End I get 1 (or 11).

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getCart', 'getCart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getCart', 'getCart' );
function getCart(){
    echo get_cart_content();
    die();
    return;
}
```

```
function get_cart_content() {
    $cartContent = '';
    $cartContent = require_once('wps-cart-content.php');
    $cartContent .= require_once('wps-cart-footer.php');
    return $cartContent;
}
```

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
       action: 'getCart',
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHT, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {console.log('Fehler');}
});
```

I noticed, that the function returns only one time 1, if I'd call `require_once` only once.
If I return a value without calling  `get_cart_content()`, there is also no 1 at the End of my code

I tried a lot... like
dataType: html or json and json_decode. I also tried require, require_once, include_once include etc.
There is always 11 at the End of the Code... and also if I log the code, it's commented out, but if I put it in my document, it's displayed normally. I guess this is no issue, but could help.

```
            <!-- <a  href=" " class="button wps-sc-cont btn"></a> -->
    </div>
   </div>   
</div>11
```

Comment: remove echo and check it's work or not

Comment: _“Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1”_ (from the manual on `include`; `require`/`require_once` behaves the same.) The exception to that would be the if the included file actually _returned_ anything, but the ones you are using apparently don’t. The create output directly (which will go into the output buffer directly), so all you are appending to your variable there are those `1` the require statement returns. And since you are returning and echo-ing that, you get output of those files first, assigned return values of require_once statements second.

Comment: But the Files are returning what I want. The return the correct data. Except, there is a 1 appended to each one. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change code as per below.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getCart', 'getCart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getCart', 'getCart' );

function getCart(){
    $response = array(
        'type' => 'success',
        'html' => get_cart_content()
    );
    wp_send_json_success($response);
    wp_die();
}
function get_cart_content() {
    ob_start();
    require_once('wps-cart-content.php');
    require_once('wps-cart-footer.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
       action: 'getCart',
    },
    success: function (data) {
        switch(res.data.type) {
                case 'success' :
                       console.log(res.data.html)
                    break;
                case 'failure' :

                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
    },
    error: function (jqXHT, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {console.log('Fehler');}
});
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. I am using it without ```datatype: 'json'``` but with  ```ob_start();``` and return ```ob_get_clean();``` and it works!
Thanks!

Comment: It didnt work for me. Number 1 is still at the end of response content.